# Olá, estou aprendendo HTML e CSS e estou tendo dificuldades para tirar essa parte branca? podem ajudar a mostrar onde errei

Tags: input, label

[código completo executado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX85c.png)
HTML

```
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
            <div class="input"> 
            <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i>
            <input id="nome" placeholder="Seu Nome" type="text">
            </div>
```

CSS
#form{
display: flex;
position: relative;
top: 53%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
border-radius: 10px;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ffffff;
padding: 30px;
width:min-content ;
color: #ffffff;
}

.input{
min-width: 500px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:2px #c87a7a solid;
margin:2% ;
}

.input
{
padding: 7px;
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #32d7a5, #804141, #000000);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-backface-visibility: text;
}

Answer (score -1):

Não consegui identificar muito bem, se mandar o código inspecionado no browser seria um pouco melhor, mas pelo jeito parece que a sua tag `<input>` está com os estilos padrão, no seu css tenta aplicar o seguinte código:

```
.input {
//seu código 
} 

.input > input {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado.